# How can select different items in lists and put a number for every output?

Tags: python

```
import random
actions = ["act1","act2","act3","act4",
"act5","act6"]
subjects =[,"sub1","sub2","sub3",
"sub4","sub5","sub6"]
s1 = len(actions)
s2 = len(subjects)
num = 0
while True:
    if num < (s1*s2)+1:
        num += 1
        actions += subjects
        print(random.sample(actions+subjects,3))
```

I want to sort 2 lists with combination but when i print this  code some outputs printing sometimes same acts or subs (ex: [act1,act1,sub5]) but I don't want that.

I want every output be different, if combination over, it should stop printing. And other thing I want, it give numbers for every output. For example :
line1 : 1.[act1,sub3,act,4] 
line2 : 2.[act2,sub2,act1]
...
....
....

How can i make this?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the expected out put . the first line is not clear

Comment: You should watch out, seems to me like you have a infinite loo, you should put an ending conditon and use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: can you put your desired output more clearly, so that will more clear to answer you @ArdaAltun

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the followind code is what you're looking for, have a look:

```
import itertools

actions = ["act1","act2","act3","act4","act5","act6"]
subjects =["sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub5","sub6"]

comb = map(' '.join, itertools.chain(itertools.product(actions, subjects)))

i = 0
for element in comb:
    print("{}. {}".format(i, element))
    i += 1
```